# give attributes to multiple menu items in wordpress (no .js)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, function

i'm trying to give an attribute for each item in my wordpress navbar.

what i have now is this:

```
  <ul id="menu-nav-bar" class="menu">

        <li><a href="#text">text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#carousel">carousel</a></li>

  </ul>
```

and this is what i'm trying to achive:

```
  <ul id="menu-nav-bar" class="menu">

        <li><a data-menuanchor="text" href="#text">text</a></li>
        <li><a data-menuanchor="text" href="#carousel">carousel</a></li>

  </ul>
```

i used a custom walker to create the menu, so would be cool if i can use a function to get the text inside the < a > tags (which is text and carousel in this case) and make it "print" in data-menuanchor attribute like the example above.

this is a preatty similar case, but it's not working for me:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/165294/how-to-add-scroll-ids-to-wordpress-menu-anchors

Comment: _"i used a custom walker to create the menu"_ Then share your walker code.

Comment: @vard it's a big chuck of code. would take 2 pages lol

Comment: Then extract the relevant parts. If you written yourself the walker that generate the HTML, you could easily change the output to add the attribute, no?

Comment: i didn't write it, i found it around... i just figure out i should write it myself.

Comment: @vard i also need to give a class active to the first < li >, i might have found a tutorial on youtube

Comment: Just being curious, why you just don't use the default wordpress menu functions?

Comment: @vard i'm pretty new with wordpress, php. so i don't really know what's the best choice, i just really need to add the class active and the data-menuachor to my menu items.

Comment: Use [`wp_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) and the `items_wrap` attribute to add your attribute. The active class is already handled by the function. [How to create a menu in Wordpress ?](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide)

Answer (score 1):

If you dont find plugin useful try this one 
Filter this, targetting a specific menu id is easy:

Add the following to your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_attribs', 10, 3 );

function my_nav_menu_attribs( $atts, $item, $args )
{
 // The ID of the target menu item
 $menu_target = 365;
// inspect $item

 if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
$atts['data-menuanchor'] = 'text';
}
 return $atts;
}
```

Comment: thank you! this is working! how can i give more than 1 target?

Comment: @tushar_sharma i mean i have to give a different anchor for each list item, how can i say that?

Comment: just add  $atts['your attribute name'] = 'default value';   that's it

Comment: Means another  "href"   ?

Comment: the problem with this can be that: if i need to add another list item in the future i have to edit the function.php file? am i wrong?

Comment: check the site i'm working on: http://bootstraptest.co.nf . it's random but gives you the idea.

Comment: Hello So u want for all menu items?Try it my new answer

Comment: hi! the attribute should be the same as navigation label (in this case, text and carousel) so its different for each list item

Comment: FIRST <li><a data-menuanchor="text" href="#text">text</a></li> FIRST,
     SECOND <li><a data-menuanchor="carousel" href="#carousel">carousel</a></li> SECOND

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_nav_menu_attribs( $atts, $item, $args )
{ 
$items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'Main', $args ); 
foreach($items as $my_item)
{
 // The ID of the target menu item
 $menu_target = $my_item->ID;
// inspect $item

if ($item->ID == $menu_target) {
  $atts['data-menuanchor'] = 'text';
   }
 }
  return $atts;
}

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_nav_menu_attribs', 10, 3 );
```

In above `wp_get_nav_menu_items( 'Main',$args)`  function call please replace "Main"  with  your menu name

Comment: how do i add it to the code i already have? :P i'm pretty noob lol

Comment: Hello I have just add my answer Please use this one in `functions.php` file. It will definitely work.

Comment: the value gets repeated for each li, but still the same for each li

Comment: Hello @scratur YO  please use my above modified code for adding custom attribute to all menu items

Comment: every item is still getting data-menuanchor="text" :D you are so kind and patient man, i'm already lost hehe

Comment: for that u have to play with each item id using if else . if u want to do it with little code  or u have to develop plugin for adding custom attribute to each menu item

Comment: isn't possible to get the name label from worpress and "paste" it in data-menuanchor="" ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Try out following plugin:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/sweet-custom-menu/

Comment: _Why_ using a plugin when Wordpress already does what OP wants?

Comment: its user friendly  so non developer also easily can add custom attribute for use

Answer (score 0):

To get a dynamic alternative for 'text' I use

`$atts['data-menuanchor'] =  sanitize_title($item->title);`

worked for me. But I have another Problem: with the attribute "data-menuanchor" is added to the link `<a>`. But it should be added to the matching `<li>`. 
Any Help for that?